# Toast Notification not working correctly on Sony Tablet S

Tags: android, notifications, toast

I have got a Toast Notification when clicking at some button.
This Toast Notification works fine on a Smartphone, but on a Tablet it only appears when the button is clicked for the first time - afterwards the Toast Notification doesn't show up (it does on a smartphone!)

What is the difference? (OS Versions 2.3 on Smartphone and 3.1 on Tablet - target is 2.3 though in the manifest)

```
//Display Custom Toast
                        if(mToast == null){
                            mToast = new Toast(getContext());
                        } else {
                            mToast.cancel();
                        }

                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_image);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(aux.getArtwork(getContext()));

                        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_title);
                        TextView tvArtist = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_artist);
                        TextView tvChannel = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_channel);

                        tvTitle.setText(aux.getTitle());
                        tvArtist.setText(aux.getArtist());
                        tvChannel.setText(aux.getFirstChannel().toString());

                        mToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        mToast.setView(layout);
                        mToast.show();
```

Comment: Are you using by any change `toast.cancel()` method? You should try posting a code snippet with the lines you use to create the toast, although it may sound as a simple thing to do.

Comment: can you show us the code...hv u tried on other device and have you used emulator to test this...

Comment: I put in code and yes I am using .cancel() which works fine on a smartphone in order to not have the toast messages overlap each other

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the tablet. I have successfully implemented toast message on Sony S. I reckon you cross check your code and yea there will be a difference at times when you run from one platform to another. You can set the minimum sdk version to 2.3 and set the target platform to 3.1 to ensure the apps performance.